# Keep Azure self-hosted agents running and connected

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a few questions regarding Azure self-hosting.

Assume a `Windows` self-hosted agent is set up on a physical machine `M` by user `Alex`. The agent goes offline when `Alex` logs off and the machine goes to sleep. Now, when `Bob` logs into the same machine, he has to set up a different agent while the agent set up by `Alex` is still offline and not accessible by `Bob`. (Please let me know if I got something wrong here)

Is it possible to set up self-hosted agents in a way such that all users can access the same agent, 
and how can we avoid the issue of the agent going offline when the machine goes to sleep? I tried running the agent both `interactively` and `as a service`.

We do have a `Linux` cluster running so we can avoid the issue of the machine going to sleep, but accessing the agent is still a concern. Also, we only have physical machines in our lab to run `Windows` and `macOS`, and users have to log out after using them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question lacks of a definition for "professional use". As managed services like Azure DevOps/AppVeyor are for professional use (IMHO), and the agents (not self-hosted) are running under system/dedicated accounts, your description (second paragraph) does not sound professional to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If on a `Windows` server that is configured to not go to sleep, create the agent and run as a service.  I'd recommend creating the agent to run as a domain service account created just for the agent.  Logging off the remote server shouldn't impact the state of the agent.

If you run as a service, the agent can not execute UI-automation.  If you need UI-automation to execute on the agent, you will need to run it as an interactive agent.  I would still run interactively as a domain service account.  If someone were to remote into the box with a different account and it is running interactively, the agent would show up as offline.  You would need to either restart that server or log in with that agent account then disconnect correctly.

We leverage the [batch script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-self-hosted-windows-agents) provided in the Microsoft documentation for disconnecting without impacting the interactive agent.

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```